# Why is the Numpy array created from my csv file full of NaN values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I have a csv file that I want to open for an assignment using Numpy (I must use Numpy for the purpose of the assignment), but my resulting array is just full of NaN's. My csv file has 2 columns and 28 rows (27 if you exclude the header) of strings: bacterial species names in column 1 and URLs in column 2.

```
 import numpy as np
 file = open('human_skin_microbiome.csv', 'r')
 file_array = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',')
 print(file_array)

 [[nan nan]
  [nan nan]
  ...
  [nan nan]
  [nan nan]]
```

Please advise!

Comment: What if you add `skip_header=1`? Or `loose=False`?

Comment: Even with specifying dtype=None, and skip_header=1, I receive the error: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.

Comment: When I add loose=False, I receive the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Acinetobacter ursingii'

Comment: Then add the `encoding=None` parameter.  `genfromtxt` by default reads the data as floats, and puts `nan` if the string isn't a valid number.  If the file has non-number columns, you need to change the `dtype`.  I know the docs for `genfromtxt` are long and confusing, but sometimes you just have to read them.

Comment: To debug, you could print `file_array.dtype` to see what dtypes were defined auto-magically. I have had success reading CSVs with strings using `dtype=None, names=True, encoding=None`. Maybe some of your data confuses the encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying `dtype=None` and `encoding = None` in `genfromtext`

Comment: I receive the error: UserWarning: genfromtxt: Empty input file: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='human_skin_microbiome.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"

Comment: The docs for genfromtext are strangely unclear. What happens if you remove the line which opens the file and just add the file name directly? `file_array = np.genfromtxt('human_skin_microbiome.csv', delimiter=',')`

Comment: I agree, regarding the documentation! I receive my original error of an array with only "nan" elements

Comment: How about when you specify encoding =None as well as dtype?